# How to use different icons for each tab with createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `React Native Navigation v2` for my project. I am trying to set two different IonIcons with the `createBottomTabNavigator`.

Their [site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) gives an example like this:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    let iconName;
    if (routeName === 'Home') {
      iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
    } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
      iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
    }

    // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
    // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
    return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
  },
}),
```

But to me, this seems dull. Can I define the IonIcon in the component itself?
How can I define the symbols individually with React Native Navigation v2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```js
class HomeComponent extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
        },
    };

    // ...
}
```

Or:

```js
const tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeComponent,
        path: '/',
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        },
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Although the second option works as of now, I don't think this is the right solution. What If I want to have 20 routes, and for each route I need a symbol. You'll get way to many lines of code. Any other cleaner way? Because the first option would be the best option, but that solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried the first one by adjusting a little bit [this code](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/tabs-with-icons) and it looks like it works.

Comment: Option two works for me, you sent a link for option two. Option one isn't what you've sent, that is the one that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work on my end. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Although the most voted answer is right, maybe you don't want to use the solution ending with '-outline' icon version, and want to use different icons, so:

---

**CHANGE ICON (STANDARD VECTOR ONES) ON FOCUSED:**

```
tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
    <Ionicons name={focused ? 
                    'ios-home' : 
                    'ios-home-outline'} 
              size={26} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
),
```

**CHANGE ICON (USING ANY IMAGE YOU WANT) ON FOCUSED:**

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const iconimg = focused  ? 
              require('../active.png')  : 
              require('../inactive.png')
        return (
            <Image 
                source={iconimg}
                style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
        )
    }
```